# Apache Pulsar Readers

Tags: c#, websocket, apache-pulsar

I am using Apache Pulsar via WebSockets. When I use a *reader* to fetch the data from a topic, if I acknowledge the messages, will they be deleted from the topic? I have set a retention period for the namespace of that topic as such:

```
pulsar-admin namespaces set-retention public/default \
--size 1T \
--time -1
```

My setup works when I use the reader for the first time; as data comes into the topic I am able to read it.
But how come the messages cannot be accessed again using the reader.

The URL is:

> ws://someEndPoint:8080/ws/v2/reader/persistent/public/default/topicName?messageId=earliest&receiverQueueSize=100000

Answer (score 0):

When you set a retention on topics, messages **are not** deleted until the retention expires. Reader is a regular non-persistent subscription with random subscription name. In case of C# you can use [native .net client](https://github.com/fsharplang-ru/pulsar-client-dotnet) as well.